# Filter JavaScript object array by indexof

Tags: typescript

All the answers for this seems to be using exact matching, I am looking to use indexOf for partial matches.

My array is like this:

```
[{fName: 'John'}, {fName: 'Johnny'}, {fName: 'Sally'}]
```

I have a text field set up to call a function every time a new character is typed. I would like to be able to take user input and filter the array down once they start typing so if they type 'J', it should return back the John object and the Johnny object. If I do exact matching with 'John' it returns the correct object but not with partial matches. This is what I have so far:

```
this.nameArray.filter((name) => {
      return this.textInputValue.indexOf(name.fName) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Just use indexof for the name.fName instead of the textInputValue

Comment: @lleon can you submit an answer, I am not sure how to change what I have to what your suggesting.

Comment: Just swap `textInputValue` and `name.fName`

Comment: @Andreas then how do I compare the value the user is entering to name.fName if I remove the textInputValue?

Comment: Where did I say that you should remove `textInputValue` (what ever this exactly means for you)? Just do `name.fName.indexOf(textInputValue)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.nameArray.filter((name) => {
      return userInput===name.fName.substring(0, userInput.length);
});
```

Comment: It will return John & Johnny when input is 'John'

Comment: @PranavRamachandran And the problem is? OP asks for exactly this behavior (_"if they type 'J', it should return back the John object and the Johnny object"_)

Comment: That's the idea. John is a partial match for Johnny